# What is "0 down vote favorite"?

Tags: support, voting, bookmarks, waffles

I recently reviewed a First Post that began with "0 down vote favorite." I figured it was just some weird thing that was written in that question, but then I searched on Stack Overflow for the phrase "0 down vote favorite." It popped up plenty of questions and answers from different users that began in the same way, and oddly enough, none were down voted. Next, I tried an internet search for "0 down vote favorite." It showed Stack Exchange questions that began with that phrase, and some other sites with a similar situation. A search on Meta shows nothing.

Is this some internet phrase that I am missing? Is it some bug with Stack Exchange that prepends it to certain questions? Is it just people trying to say "don't down-vote this, please favorite this?"

Answer (score 76, accepted):

When you copy content from a post and by mistake catch the vote block while marking then you get that text.

Marking like this

[image: Example marking text]

results in

> 0
>   down vote
>   favorite
>   I recently reviewed

That is a good opportunity to go through that [69 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down+vote+favorite%22) and  improve them...

Comment: p.s: You were right with *question*; answers don't have a "favorite" button ;)

Comment: Not all results with down vote favorite in them are necessarily invalid

Comment: @Matt: [Looks like there's a few of them as well](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%220+down+vote%22).

Comment: Reviewing 20 pending edits has never been so quick! 15 maybe 18 out of 20 were related to this question ^^

Comment: How could they don't see that when pasting the text? Why are they blindly copy-pasting something? I've seen this for a lot of duplicate (old) posts.

Comment: @FelipeAls: Shame many of them should have been rejected as *too minor*, as they failed to fix ***anything*** else wrong with the post... yes [troniczomb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2069587/troniczomb), I'm looking at the edits you suggested.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn Often because they've cross posted the question – try and see if you find the duplicates on Google :)

Comment: @slhck Yes, I've already done that and found the duplicate ones.

Comment: 29
down vote
accepted
When you copy content from a post and by mistake... **|** I tried doing the same on this answer and that's what I got, so it works on answers too